# Drupal URLs migrated to new WordPress installation

Tags: wordpress, redirect, drupal

We have an existing Drupal site. That is going to be replaced with a WordPress site on the existing URL. However, there has been a lot of SEO done on the drupal URLs so a google search will return those old URL's. We want to redirect to the new corresponding URL in the Wordpress site. However, since the drupal site is no longer live on the existing domain, the old URL's will just return 404 and cannot be redirected since they are not relative to the WordPress root. Is there a way to do this? Do I need to get those old drupal site URLs into WordPress somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to update your sitemap and add canonical's for permanent redirections. This wont directly redirect the page, but will let the search engines know that the url for the page has been changed and hence will avoid loosing your search engine rankings.

Then for actually redirecting the page you will need to update your htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /folder/oldpage http://www.example.org/newpage
```

If there are lots of pages you should consider using a wordpress plugin called [redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). This way you dont have to update the htaccess manually, and it will also keep logs of all the 404 pages that users have found, so you can also keep an eye on logs for any missing pages and redirect them accordingly.

Comment: In other words change canonical to something like "legacy/example.com/oldpage" so that the seach engine knows that it should now look in that folder, and then get the redirect eithe through htaccess or a plugin?

Comment: Yes you are right, but search engines wont look in those folders right away, they will just keep track of it for a time. Afterwards they will forget about the old urls and permanently redirect to new ones. At that point, you can even disable the redirect plugin. Once you are done with setting everything up, you should create a google webmasters account and update the site map.